# Can PMI be used after LRT on candidate features for further purification of features?

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

Likelihood Ratio Test(LRT) can be used for relevance scoring in candidate features to find the most relevant features. After this, can we use Point-wise Mutual Information(PMI) for further purification of features?

Comment: By further purification I mean to create key features group after using LRT using WordNet, then I need to make further key features groups by combining candidate features CF and key features group in order not to loose infrequent features. CF can be similar to the group of key features, can be different but similar semantically, or totally different. There is cosine function but don't really know what's that?